# Examining the theorem, for all $\epsilon \gt 0$, if $x \le y + \epsilon$, then $x \le y$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, ordered-fields

For this theorem, I understand the case in which x $\lt y + \epsilon$. From there it follows visually that x could either be equivalent to y itself, or x could also be less than y; in either case, the conclusion holds. However, is it always the case that x $\lt y + \epsilon$? Is it even possible for 
$x = y + \epsilon$ for all epsilon? Because if this were true, wouldn't our conclusion that 
$x \le y$ be false? Wouldn't $x \gt y$?

Comment: Equality can never hold - if $x=y+\varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon>0$, then by assumption $x\leq y+\varepsilon/2$, a contradiction.

Comment: Perhaps you have been misled by your own imprecision. The statement of the theorem has to be "If $x\le y+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$, then $x\le y$." Your statement of the theorem doesn't make any sense -- the order matters.

Comment: It is possible for some $\epsilon$ that $x = y + \epsilon$, but not all.

Answer (score 0):

I will show epsilon by E
You can see it like this way, x-y<=E. It means, x-y should always be less than or equal to any positive element(E) of field.
If x=y+E for all E>0 then x is variable, not fixed but we deal with fixed values of x and y which can follow the given inequality for variable E.
If x is considered fixed in x=y+E, then order properties of field is ruled out! (x=y+1 and x=y+2 for fixed x and y is not possible).
So we have to find the possibilities of inequalities between x and y.
So possibilities are x<=y.